# Check for vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given

$$U = \{(x, y)\mid x, y \in \mathbb R \land 2x - 3y = \alpha\},$$
for which $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ would $U$ be a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^2$?

Answer:
Considering the fact that for U to be a vector subspace of R^2 (R), we need the vector `(0,0)` to be included in U, therefore, $\alpha$ has be `0` (by definition).

$(x,y) = (0,0)$

So, we get $2x - 3y = \alpha$ and therefore $2x - 3y = 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $U$ is to be a subspace of $\mathbb R$, then we need for the zero vector $(0, 0)$ to be in $U\subseteq \mathbb R^2$. What must $\alpha$ be to ensure this?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly to start this, but does that mean `2x - 3y = 0`?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it does!

Comment: So, how exactly am I gonna solve this? It's one equation with two unknowns, I never faced such a problem before.

Comment: The question asks what $\alpha = 2x -3y$ needs to be for $U$ to be a subspace of $\mathbb R$. And you found that $\alpha$ needs to be $0$. You're done, and you've got the reason why it must be $0$. It certainly wouldn't hurt to confirm that $U = \{(x, y)\mid 2x - 3y = 0\}$ is then, indeed, a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Nice hint! +1 ;-)

Comment: So, you're saying that the solution of this is enough to say that `α = 2x - 3y` needs to be `0`. Nothing else to be written in the solution?

Comment: You need to say that for $U$ to be a subspace, $\alpha$ needs to be $0$, and *why* it needs to be zero. You seem to understand why it must be zero, per the hint. One criteria of a subspace $U$ of $\mathbb R^2$ is that $(x, y) = (0, 0)\in U$. This requires $\alpha$ to be zero.

Comment: Ok, well, I have to say that with words, or I have to say/prove it mathematically? Also, as per the hint you've given I understand that α has to be `0` to be a vector subspace of R, because the vector (0,0) MUST be in it too.

Comment: Words are enough: you need to give the value of $\alpha$, and explain (in words) why $\alpha = 0$. And yes, you are are right regarding the hint.

Comment: Alright, just one question, may be a bit off-topic. Is it necessary to take (0,0) vector in all examples of this kind? Why do we need the zero vector and not other one?

Comment: @user95523: In order to be a vector (sub)space, a zero vector is required, by definition.

Comment: Can you check if my answer in first post is correct? I updated it

Comment: @amWhy: Nice hint +1